# make studies of/on biology

Tags: idioms

I know there is an idiom "make study of".  But I think it's incorrect to say

> He made studies of biology.

because "biology" is not an exact thing you examine.

Then, how can I express that?

> He made studies on biology.

Will that make sense?

Comment: You can say _He made a study of biology_ (he studied it as an academic subject), or _He made studies in biology_ (He studied particular topics in the field of biology).

Comment: @Kate Bunting Ah, now I understand! Thank you very much!!